# Transparency with UpdateLayeredWindow

Tags: c++, winapi

I have layered window (`WS_EX_LAYERED`), and I am trying to display a bitmap on the window using `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

The bitmap is an irregular shape with a solid background color `RGB(30, 30, 30)`. I would like to make the background transparent using the `ULW_COLORKEY` option.

When I call `UpdateLayeredWindow` the image is rendered on the screen, but the background is not transparent.

```
    // Draw background rectangle
    COLORREF transparent_colour = RGB(30, 30, 30);
    HBRUSH hTranparentBrush = CreateSolidBrush(transparent_colour);
    HBRUSH hOldBrush = SelectObject(hSrcDC, hTransparentBrush);

    // the rectangle is the size of the splash screen / layered window
    hresult =  Rectangle(hSrcDC, 0, 0, szSplash.cx, szSplash.cy);
    //error checking has been removed

    // Paint rotated bitmap over background
    hresult = SetGraphicsMode(hSrcDC, GM_ADVANCED);

    float s = math::sin(degree * pi / 180);
    float c = math::cos(degree * pi / 180);
    XFORM x;
    x.em11 = c;
    x.em12 = s;
    x.em21 = -s;
    x.em22 = c;
    x.eDx = (1-c)*szImg.cx + s*szImg.cy;
    x.eDy = (1-c)*szImg.cy - s*szImg.cx;

    hresult = SetWorldTransform(hSrcDC, x);

    // the BitBlt below succeeds. hSrcDC contains a bitmap with a solid
    // background and the rotated image over it.
    hresult = BitBlt(hSrcDC, 100, 100, szImg.cx, szImg.cy, hImgDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Print to screen
    POINT ptZero = {0, 0};

    SIZE szBmp = szSplash; //size of the splash screen

    BLENDFUNCTION blend;
    blend.BlendOp = ARC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.BlendFlags = 0;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    //this call succeeds - the bitmap is printed to the screen, but the
    //background is still visible?
    hresult = UpdateLayeredWindow(hwndSplash, 
                                  hSplashDC, 
                                  &ptZero, 
                                  &szBmp, 
                                  hSrcDC, 
                                  &ptZero, 
                                  transparent_colour, 
                                  &blend, 
                                  ULW_COLORKEY);
```

If I replace `ULW_COLORKEY` with `ULW_ALPHA` then both the background and other parts of the image become transparent and it looks bad. I ony want the background to be transparent - is there something I am missing?

Comment: Could you please post what values are in your params (ptZero, ptZero, blend)?

Comment: `&hSrcDC` should be `hSrcDC` for one thing, but without more code we can't know if you've done anything else wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have added more code.